# Android minifyEnable release compile and Apache FTPServer library

Tags: android

I've been working with an application which uses Apache FTP Server as library, all works fine until I compile the project with minifyEnable on and generate a signed apk, many warns come's out, and if I add don't warn, it compiles successfully, but some bugs occur in run time.

Does it mean I should compile the library with source if I what to enable minify? If so, how can I use the src.jar as a source lib and compile it?

Comment: can u share your logcat.

Comment: @Shekhar since this problems only comes up under minified release building, so logcat is not applicable. Therefore I caught the exception by Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHander() and obtained that `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:class a.a.c.c.a.a.a must have a public constructor with one ExecutorService parameter, a public constructor with one Executor parameter or a public default constructor.  a.a.c.a.f.m#(null:-1) ...` it is meaningless but is all the information I can get

Comment: I think you have the same error as I have: 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor must have a public constructor with one ExecutorService parameter, a public constructor with one Executor parameter or a public default constructor.
        at org.apache.mina.core.service.SimpleIoProcessorPool.<init>(Unknown Source:349)
     
I added it to the proguard-rules.pro

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by adding the following to the proguard-rules.pro file which sets up the rules for the minifying process / obfuscation:

```
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
```

This keeps the source code of org.apache.ftpserver, org.apache.mina etc from being obfuscated.

Hope this helps :)